# How can I connect an hid device to web app?

Tags: javascript, hid, webhid

I want to connect an HID device to my web app, by USB connection.

The WebUSB API does not suit to me, because the device is an HID device(when using the WebUSB API, after `device.open()` there are an error: `'Access Denied.'`).

I wanted to use the WebHID API, but for now, this is not available. ([WebHID API](https://wicg.github.io/webhid))

Does anyone know how to connect the device to the WEB app anyway?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The WebHID API is actually available on all desktop platforms (ChromeOS, Linux, macOS, and Windows) in Chrome 89. See https://developer.chrome.com/articles/hid/#browser-support

Can you share why WebHID is not working for you?

Comment: Now it works very well with the WebHID API.
My question was written 3 years ago... at that time the API was not available yet

Comment: Oh got it! Sorry ;)